# Can't access class methods from JavaScript when trying scripting

Tags: java, nashorn

I'm trying to test out JavaScript through Java using simple Nashorn examples, and I'm just not understanding why I can't access a method of my own class from a JS call.

First, the class I want to work with:

```
package myPackage;

public class myClass
{
    Object internalObj;


    static boolean test()
    {
        return true;
    }

    boolean storeObject(Object obj)
    {
        internalObj = obj;
        return true;
    }

    String whatObjectType()
    {
        return internalObj.getClass().toString();
    }

}
```

Then, the code that is to provide scripting calls:

```
package myPackage;

import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class myTester
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println(">> Script Testing");

        //test out my class
        System.out.println(myClass.test());

        myClass myObj = new myClass();

        myObj.storeObject("test");

        System.out.println(myObj.whatObjectType());

        //now try the same from javascript
        ScriptEngine js = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("javascript");

        String myScript ="var myJSClass = Java.type('myPackage.myClass');"
                + "var myJSObj = new myJSClass();"
                + "print(myJSObj.test());";

        try
        {
            js.eval(myScript);
        } catch (ScriptException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}
```

Everything is well and good until the evaluation of myJSObj.test(), which craps out. Here's the output:

```
>> Script Testing
true
class java.lang.String
javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: myJSObj.test is not a function in <eval> at line number 1
```

Most of the Nashorn intro material shows similar examples, except they all work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I should note that replacing the call to method test() with a non-static method call results in the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. You're trying to call a non-`public` method from outside the package (your JavaScript code isn't in `myPackage`). `test` will need to be public in order for you to call it.
2. You're making the call on an *instance* of your class, not on the class itself, but `test` is `static`. Java allows calling static methods through instance references (it's one of the quirkier things about Java), but JavaScript doesn't have that concept. You'll need to make `test` an instance method, or call it on `myJSClass` instead.

Fix those, and it works. :-)

Comment: 1) Worked perfectly, thank you. I just assumed something being called from within a package would have some sort of operational context for the package itself. Curious, is there a way to include a particular script within the package? Might be useful. 2) I did not know this, thanks again.

Comment: @Diego: No worries. I doubt it's possible to put the JavaScript code in a package, not least because JavaScript isn't class-based (even when using ES2015's `class` syntax), and you can happily copy a "method" from one JavaScript "class" to another. But I don't know that for sure, they may have come up with some clever way of supporting it.